# Automating GitHub API for creating repos/Gists return 200 OK instead of 201 Created

Tags: api, postman, github-api, gist, github-api-v3

I use Postman to Create a gist and I added bearer token in the authorization Tab but it suppose to create a gist and return **201 Created** instead it returns 200 OK and it doesn't create anything
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFnLi.png)

I have written in the request body the example mentioned at GitHub Docs to create a Gist

```
{
  "description": "Hello World Examples",
  "public": true,
  "files": {
    "hello_world.rb": {
      "content": "class HelloWorld\n   def initialize(name)\n      @name = name.capitalize\n   end\n   def sayHi\n      puts \"Hello !\"\n   end\nend\n\nhello = HelloWorld.new(\"World\")\nhello.sayHi"
    },
    "hello_world.py": {
      "content": "class HelloWorld:\n\n    def __init__(self, name):\n        self.name = name.capitalize()\n       \n    def sayHi(self):\n        print \"Hello \" + self.name + \"!\"\n\nhello = HelloWorld(\"world\")\nhello.sayHi()"
    },
    "hello_world_ruby.txt": {
      "content": "Run `ruby hello_world.rb` to print Hello World"
    },
    "hello_world_python.txt": {
      "content": "Run `python hello_world.py` to print Hello World"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried as text, and use the image as supporting context. Are you using `Content-Type: application/json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/gists#create-a-gist

> Authentication You can read public gists anonymously, but you must be
> signed into GitHub to create gists. To read or write gists on a user's
> behalf, you need the gist OAuth scope and a token. For more
> information, see "Scopes for OAuth Apps."

You should be authenticated else you will have only read access, thats why you are getting 200 instead of 201

**Second Reason:**   you are using http instead of https

Use token generated from developer settings as oauth2 bearer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I got a personal access token from developer settings at github with the scope gist , I think its enough to post requests, if there any other way to get other type of token please clarify it? @PDHide

Comment: Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json are you setting this header ? remove the default accept header from postman and add this . ALso try using multiform data instead of json body to send this and see

Comment: @DeenaM.Zamzam for me its working please see the updated answer you can use body as raw>json . When you add authorization use oauth 2 , bearer token . ALso use https instead of http

Comment: @DeenaM.Zamzam ussing https instead of http will fix your issue if you are passing auth token as bearer , and accept as application/vnd.github.v3+json

Comment: Thanks a million you are genius it was the s in https @PDHide

Comment: @DeenaM.Zamzam please accept the anser and upvote by clicking the up arrow and tick sign near my answer :)